# How to write summary output?

Tags: r, vba, excel, bert-toolkit

I am trying to get output of `Summary()` function of R. I want my output in Excel. I have used BERT console to write my R function which calculates summary as below:

```
descriptive <- function(data){
  X <- summary(data)
  return(X)
}
```

I am able to run this and call in Excel as `r.descriptive` and also getting an output by selecting multiple cells and pressing the combination (Ctrl + Shift + Enter). Now, next I want to print the output using VBA.

I have used `Application.Run(BERT.Call, ..)`

But what exactly to write to get the output of summary using BERT function in VBA is confusing. I want to execute VBA code to print multiple cells output of summary function in `BERT`.

Answer (score 0):

If the spreadsheet function does exactly what you want, you can use that directly instead of using `BERT.Call`.

If you are using a spreadsheet function like `=R.descriptive(A1:F10)`, then you can do the same thing in VBA using

```
x = Application.Run("R.descriptive", Range("A1:F10"))
```